# Yandex Maps: Временно отключить события у объектов карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Суть проблемы такая: есть карта с активными объектами. Объектов много и при клике по ним выполняются различные действия.

Данные по объектам (координаты и проч.) грузятся с сервера. Необходимо на время загрузки отключать обработку событий у объектов на карте.

Пока я вижу 2 варианта:

1) во время загрузки удалять события у геообъектов, а как только загрузка закончится, восстанавливать их. Это неудобно, т.к. нужно хранить где-то все обработчики

2) хранить состояние загрузки в переменной isLoading и во все обработчики прописать в начале if(isLoading) return false;

Мне кажется, что должен быть более изящный способ отключить события у геообъектов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать более коротким способом. Спасибо!

здесь пример карты
https://jsbin.com/biqiqug/

нужно, чтобы alert при клике не появлялся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно менять модель интерактивности у геообъектов:

```
ymaps.geoQuery(group).setOptions('interactivityModel', "default#silent");
```

Почитать можно тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/#Placemark__param-options.interactivityModel

Comment: Супер! То, что нужно, спасибо. Пробовал этот вариант, но подставлял не то значение, какое надо было))